# How to uniquely identify a device using hardware parameters?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, hardware, uuid

I want to uniquely identify a device(laptop/PC) for my application.  The thing is that there is no such hardware parameters which are universally unique and cannot be changed. Like Mac address. Though it is unique, but it can easily be spoofed. So I am thinking to go with the combination of mutliple hardware parameters which increases the probability of a device being unique. Right now I am considering the following hardware parameters.

1) Mac Address

2) CPU Serial Number

3) Hard Disk Serial Number

4) MotherBoard Serial Number.

Also this should work for all platforms like (Linux/Mac/Windows). So is it the right approach or should I include more parameters to unique identify the device?

Answer (score 0):

Also you may add VendorID:ProductID of your hardware in your list.
But I cannot guarantee that it cannot be spoofed as well.